# A finite summation involving $2013$

Tags: summation

Can you help me compute the summation below?
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2013}+\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2012\cdot 2013}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdots2013}$$

Comment: I'm really not clear about what is the general term here.

Comment: Just to clarify (because the $\frac{1}{1\cdot 3}$ term is perhaps wrong), we're adding up the sums of the inverse of the product of $n$ sequential elements for all $1\leq n \leq 2013$?

Comment: So far (i.e., before corrections), this looks like a nightmare-exercise...

Comment: I have seen this question somewhere on M.SE

Comment: If having $\{1,2,3\}$ then $S=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3}$

Comment: Just so it's written down here, the general term is $1/(\textrm{product of elements of A})$, where $A$ is a subset of $\{1,\dots,2013\}$.

Answer (score 24):

Hint:

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=\left(x+1\right)\left(x+\dfrac12\right)\ldots\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2013}\right)$.

Can you relate the value $f(1)$ with your sum?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how it works for $n=3$.

Find a common denominator:

> $$\begin{align}
> 1 + S &= 1 + \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{1\cdot2} + \frac{1}{1\cdot3} + \frac{1}{2\cdot3} + \frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3}\\
> &=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3 + 2\cdot3 + 1\cdot3 + 1\cdot2 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1}{1\cdot2\cdot3}\\
> &= \frac{(1+1)(1+2)(1+3)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}\\
> &= \frac{2\cdot3\cdot4}{1\cdot2\cdot3}\\
> &= 4
> \end{align}$$
>   So, $S = 3$.

Generally, $(1 + S)n! = (x + 1)(x + 2) \cdots (x + n)\big|_{x=1} = (n + 1)!$, which gives $S = n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let denote by 
$$P=(x-2013)(x-2012)\cdots(x-1)=x^{2013}+a_{2012}x^{2012}+\cdots+a_0$$
then we know the relation between the coefficients $a_i$ and the roots:
$$\sigma_k=(-1)^ka_{2013-k}.$$
Now it's easy to see that the given sum is equal to
$$\frac{\sigma_{2012}+\cdots+\sigma_1+1}{\sigma_{2013}}.$$